# Flex TileGrid: Why do you default to copying when I drag and drop your items?

Tags: apache-flex, tilelist

Why is it that, when I enable dragging-and-dropping in a TitleGrid, items are copied when they are dragged instead of moved?

For example:

```
<mx:TileList dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:Array>
            <mx:Object label="Nokia 6630"/>
            <mx:Object label="Nokia 6680"/>
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:TileList>
```

When either of those items is clicked-and-dragged, it will get copied instead of moved.

This is especially confusing because TileList is a decedent of ListBase, which DataGrid also descends from...  But DataGrid does the right thing when dragging and dropping items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please test following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:TileList dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:Array>
                <mx:Object label="Nokia 6630"/>
                <mx:Object label="Nokia 6680"/>
            </mx:Array>
        </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:TileList>

    <mx:TileList dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" />

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

The solution of your problem is dragMoveEnabled="true".
Hope that helps.